# Linux mint freezes after clicking on run button in android studio

Tags: linux-mint, android, adb

[image]
I have installed android studio in linux mint 18.1. Every thing is working file but whenever I'm clicking on run app button it freezes completely after that I need to restart laptop. My spec is Pentium quad core with 4 gb ram. I have insteed 32 bit library also.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I used the Virtual Device and solved it by changing the graphic emulated performance back to Software.

Answer (score 0):

The screen is freezing because the emulator is set up to run on software emulated performance mode which does not use GPU so instead it grabs so much CPU that it just freezes your main OS UI. The solution is to make the emulator run on GPU so that way it does not eat all of CPU and memory.

To configure the emulator follow steps bellow:

1. Go to virtual devices window
2. select to edit your AVD
3. In `Emulated performance` change to hardware
4. Click finish